# Terminate currently running process other than Esc key in R language?

Tags: r, keyboard-shortcuts

In `R`, when you want to terminate a currently running process and type in another command immediately, you can use `esc` key to stop the process (it doesn't work at times, especially if you work with huge, huge computational work though). However, since `esc` key is far from the standard position of your fingers, I find it better to map another key or key combinations to `esc`, for example, `Ctrl+C`, and make it work similarly as do other programs/application (such as on `Terminal`). Is it feasible to make such a custom key remapping in R? And if that's the case, how can I do? I'm talking on the canonically supported GUI version of R, not sure whether those kind of settings are feasible in other environments, say `RStdio`.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm guessing you're using Windows and you mean you're using Rgui.exe but you should mention that in your question just to be completely clear.  My guess is the answer is no - you can't do what you want to do but I could be wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I use OS X. When I run R on Terminal, I can terminate the process by `Ctrl+C`, which is definitely what I want to do also on GUI version.